# Open input file with hidden visibility JS

Tags: javascript, file-upload, visibility

I have an input file with hidden visibility :

```
        <input type="file" id="fileupload" name="upload"  style="visibility: hidden;" />
```

But I want to use it, without showing it. I will trigger the event through a-tag(hyperlink). 
There I have:

```
//that's fine, open file dialog
document.getElementById('fileupload').click();

//can not take the value of file chosen?
var x = document.getElementById('fileupload').value;
console.log(x);
```

So how can I take the chosen file without displaying the input ? Is this possible?

Comment: You need to add another handler to your file input, a `onchange` one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only want to display the filename when someone adds a file?

You could add an eventListener to your file to retrieve the filename:

```
document.getElementById('fileupload').onchange = function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value);
}
```

But to upload a file you can just add this hidden file field to a form and submit it.

Answer (score -1):

The first question in my mind is why dont you use jQuery, as its easier.

Second, the input will not actually hold the file per se, but a reference to it. The file will be sent via post (or get) and manipulated server side. Maybe I don't understand correctly what you're trying to do.

Comment: I wouldn't use GET to upload a file.

Comment: Trying to open and take the file chosen's name without showing the 'Choose File' button

Comment: I sincerely recommend jQuery. If so you could use something like $("fileupload").on('change', function(){ $(this).val() <-- this is the file name, do something with it});